# Trying to understand haskell's code

Tags: haskell

Here is a Haskell code which compiles:

```
class Category categ where
  method1 :: categ a a
  method2 :: categ a b -> categ b c -> categ a c
```

But I don't understand its meaning:

1. what's `categ`? how can it be defined: through `data` or `class`? maybe
   this is a `function`?
2. what are `a` and `b` and `c`? since they are not specified as

   ```
   class Category categ a b c where
       method1 :: categ a a
       method2 :: categ a b -> categ b c -> categ a c
   ```

   this code shouldn't compile, should it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
class Category categ where
```

This is a type class declaration,

It declares a type class called `Category`. The `categ` is the variable used to refer to the a type implementing `Category` in the associated functions. Later you will fill it when you say

```
instance Category Foo where
    ....
```

Then wherever `categ` is used in the type class methods, you substitute `Foo` and define the methods.

Read it out loud as "A type `categ` is a `Category` if it has the following methods"

---

Now for the methods:

```
method1 :: categ a a
method2 :: categ a b -> categ b c -> categ a c
```

Declares 2 functions that any type implementing `Category` must implement. The first one is a no argument function which returns, for any type `a`, the type `categ a a`. `method2` takes in two pieces of data, `categ a b` and `categ b c`, and returns `categ a c`.

Here `a b c` are type variables, they are placeholders that are filled with arbitrary concrete types when the function is called. If you're familiar with C++ or Java,

```
template<typename A>
categ<A, A> method1();
```

is pretty close to what you have in Haskell. In Haskell, we just use type variables without declaring them. They are function local, and equivalent to saying something like, *For any type `a`, the following code works*.

---

This is pretty fundamental to Haskell, I'd recommend reading [Learn You A Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/). It's free and will cover all aspects of the code you just posted.

Comment: I'm asking `instance Category Foo where` -- how Foo could be defined: through class or data or something else? Could it be a function?

Comment: @MariusKavansky Can you explain what you mean by "how can it be a function"?

Comment: @MariusKavansky `Foo` would have to be a concrete type (defined as `data` or `newtype`) of kind `* -> * -> *`, i.e. it has to take two type variables. And it could be the _type of functions_ `(->)`, if you meant that.

Comment: @phg, this is exactly what I mean. Could it be `class` also?

Comment: No, not directly, as classes are not like types. What you can do is making all instances of one class instances of another class, like `instance Monad m => Category (Kleisli m) where ...`

Comment: @MariusKavansky I suggest you read learn you a haskell. This is nicely explained in there